# only display certain hours with d3.js

Tags: d3.js

I'm charting stock prices with an interval of ten minutes and length of 10 days.  Of course the stock market is only open between 9:30 and 4.  How do I only display the portion of the chart that is between 9:30am and 4?  For example google finance charts https://www.google.com/finance?q=AAPL

```
var margin = {top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 10, left: 10};
var width = $('#'+stock.symbol+'_graph').width() - margin.left - margin.right;
var height = 100 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom");
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left");

var line = d3.svg.area()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y1(function(d) { return y(d.price); })
    .y0(height);

var svg = d3.select('#'+stock.symbol+'_graph').append('svg')
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

x.domain(d3.extent(stockHistory, function(d) { return d.date; }));
y.domain(d3.extent(stockHistory, function(d) { return d.price; }));

svg.append("path")
    .datum(stockHistory)
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", line);
```

Comment: The easiest would probably be to only have those hours in your data to start with.

Comment: That's how it is, there's no data for those hours the market is not open.

Comment: Ah right, sorry, got you now. You could use a categorical scale for the time, although that would make other things a bit clunky.

Comment: use only d3.time.scale() for a continus Time axis

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing that you want to display not just the part of the chart between 9:30 and 4:00, but that range of each day.

You can do this by compressing the rest of the hours into the same part of the range, which can be accomplished by utilizing the fact that d3 scales can take a range of values. For example, let's say I have the following data:

```
var data = [
    {x:0, y:2},{x:0.5, y:2.2},{x:1.3,y:5},{x:2.0,y:3},
    {x:10,y:2},{x:10.7,y:4.6},{x:11.3,y:0},{x:12,y:2}
    ];
```

My data only has values in the ranges [0,2] and [10,12], so I'd like to display only those values.

I start by setting up a scale for the x-values, like so:

```
var xscale = d3.scale.linear()
```

Now I need to set the domain.

```
    .domain([0,2,10,12])
```

This slices my domain, effectively, into three parts: [0,2] , [2,10] , and [10,12]. If I similarly give a range with an array of four values, I can crate a piecewise linear scale. Let's say that I have a 500x500 SVG I'm plotting in. I want to map each interesting section of my domain to half of my svg, with a bit of padding on the edges, and map the entire boring middle section to a single value. To do this, I supply the following range:

```
    .range([10,250,250,490])
```

Now I have the following three mappings on my piecewise linear scale: [0,2] -> [10,250] , [2,10] -> [250,250] , and [10,12] -> [250,490]. I've effectively sliced out the middle of my domain.

I also need to fix the tick values, since if I plot this with an x-axis, d3 won't be smart enough to not try to plot any values for the section of the domain that I've collapsed into a single pixel. I can do this by explicitly declaring my tick values:

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(xscale)
    .orient('bottom')
    .tickValues([0,1,2,11,12])
```

I've created a fiddle of this simple example [here.](http://jsfiddle.net/jPhDD/) The same method could be applied to paths instead of circles to get the effect shown in your example.

In order to make this nice, readable, and scalable to multiple days, you would just need to write functions to generate your domain, range, and tick value arrays, though adding some linear dividers to separate time periods would make things much easier.

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot.  I have one problem.  The ticks show up as timestamps like "1,373,646,600,021".  I can't figure out how to make them dates.

Comment: You can use `date = new Date(time)` to convert from a timestamp for a date, `var format = d3.time.format('%c')` or some similar format to build a d3 time formatter, and then use `format(date)` to convert to dates. See the d3.time module for more information. You might also want to look into d3 time scales, which I believe have built in time formatting, though I haven't used them.

Comment: .tickFormat(d3.time.format('%x')) worked.