# How to hide time interval on chart using d3.js v4?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I have a problem with a chart using d3.js. I want to hide a specific time interval from the chart, the interval is static (example: from 16:00 to 18:00). Do I need to create a custom scale where this interval is not used, or d3.js can provide a simple solution?

[image: the chart]

```
var width = 960,
    height = 500;

var fmtMonth = d3.time.format("%b");
var date1 = new Date(2018, 9, 26);
var date2 = new Date(2018, 9, 27);
var date3 = new Date(2018, 9, 28);
var date4 = new Date(2018, 9, 29);

var dates = [date1, date2, date3, date4];


var vis = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

var linear = vis.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(20, 10)"),
    polyLinear = vis.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(20, 100)");


// poly linear scale
var tickWidth = (940) / (dates.length - 1);

var range = dates.map(function (d, i) { return (i * tickWidth); });

var polylinearTimeScale = d3.time.scale()
  .domain(dates)
  .range(range);

var polylinearAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(polylinearTimeScale);

var ticks = polylinearTimeScale.ticks();

// Filter by removing 6 hours
var displayTicks = ticks.filter(date => date.getHours() !== 6);



polylinearAxis.tickValues(displayTicks);
polylinearAxis.tickFormat(d3.time.format("%H:%M"))


polyLinear.append("g").attr("class", "x axis").call(polylinearAxis);
```

With this code I get [image]

As you can see there is space between 00:00 and 12:00 that should not be. I wath to clear this space from chart, so the width between 00:00 and 12:00 to be like width between 12:00 and 18:00

Comment: Can you filter your data set?

Comment: do you have any code to show us?

Comment: @ksav i don't need to filter data, because the data don't contain this time interval

Comment: Perhaps filter out any zero value data points from your dataset and then create an ordinal scale. If you add some code to your question, someone will be able to help you.

Comment: @ksav added example code that show what i want to get

Comment: Do you have an example of the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to massage your data structure into a more usable format. Then use either ordinal or band scales.

```js
const width = 600;
const height = 200;


const data = [{
    val: 10,
    date: "Mon 12:00"
  },
  {
    val: 1,
    date: "Mon 18:00"
  },
  {
    val: 7,
    date: "Tue 12:00"
  },
  {
    val: 3,
    date: "Tue 18:00"
  },
  {
    val: 9,
    date: "Wed 12:00"
  },
  {
    val: 5,
    date: "Wed 18:00"
  }
]

const xDomain = data.map((x) => x.date)


const vis = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

const ordinalAxis = vis.append("g")

const x = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .domain(xDomain)
  .rangeBands([0, width]);

const xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .orient("bottom")

vis.append("g")
  .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${height-30})`)
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .call(xAxis);

const barGroup = vis.append('g')

barGroup.selectAll('rect')
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append('rect')
  .attr('x', d => x(d.date))
  .attr('y', d => height - d.val * 15 - 30)
  .attr('width', width / data.length)
  .attr('height', d => d.val * 15)
```

```css
.axis text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #1c647e;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

rect {
  fill: #55accf
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For this case, what you intend to do is to manipulate the DOM. But for D3 (**data-driven documents**), you need to think about the data. For the periods that you want to hide, you can generate or filter the data to remove them, then your graph automatically reflect the change.

Edit: 
After your comment, you can accomplish this by using answer from [@ckersch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2066336/ckersch): [only display certain hours with d3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17574970/only-display-certain-hours-with-d3-js)

Comment: there is no data in that interval, that is why i want to hide them

Comment: see modified answer above.